# emacs list files with less information

Tags: dired

Hi How can I use emacs find to list files without their detailed information?

```
C-x C-f
```

What I got:

```
-r--r--r-- user 3845 Apr 10 2014 ua.cpp
-r--r--r-- user 3845 Apr 10 2014 ub.cpp
-r--r--r-- user 3845 Apr 10 2014 uc.cpp
```

What I want:

```
ua.cpp ub.cpp uc.cpp
```

Comment: Why not `M-! ls` ?

Comment: I suggest using the `dired+` package with `diredp-hide-details-initially-flag` set to `t`.

Comment: Did you mean `C-x d` instead of `C-x C-f`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

M-x list-directory (key C-x C-d) is probably what you want?

or

M-x dired, then
M-x dired-hide-details-mode

If you always want to hide detail, add a hook. Like this:

```
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'dired-hide-details-mode)
```

If you really want them all in a single line, M-x shell-command (M-!) and `ls -m` is probably the best.

Or, better I think is just M-x eshell, then do `ls`.

Comment: `(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'dired-hide-details-mode)` would also work.

Comment: thx @npostavs, I'll edit to use your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

You can use whatever `ls` switches (command-line options) you want, for any particular Dired listing, by using a prefix argument with the Dired commands.
For example: **`C-u C-x d`**.  You are prompted for the `ls` switches to use.

And you can set your own preference for the `ls` switches to use *by default* each time, just by customizing user option **`dired-listing-switches`**:

```
M-x customize-option RET dired-listing-switches RET
```

Then, each time you use Dired, you will get the kind of listing you prefer, and if you ever want to override your preference you just use a prefix argument (`C-u`).

And whenever you are in Dired you can *toggle whether to show the details* (whatever they are, as determined by the `ls` switches), using **`(`**.